# What is a word for "to state facts as opinion"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, dictionaries

Stating opinions as facts is called dogmatism. Then what is stating facts as opinions called?

example sentence: *They     __________  on the statistics so that the statistics fit their own agenda.*

Comment: Did they interpret the statistics so that the statistics fit their own agenda?  I'm not clear on the meaning of the word you are looking for.  Or misinterpret?  Or twist?

Answer (score 0):

**opinionize**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opinionize)

> (intransitive) To claim matters of fact as opinion.

---

a more standardly-used word, but which doesn't quite mean the same thing is **opine**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/opine)

> to hold or express an opinion.

---

**opinionate**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/opinionate)

> 1 [WITH OBJECT] To hold as an opinion; = opine, opinion; to believe, suppose, think.
>
> 2 [NO OBJECT] To form, hold, or give an opinion.
>
> 4 [NO OBJECT] To state or deliver an opinion formally; = opine. rare .